# How to get all social bookmarks of any website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reddit, digg, delicious-api, stumbleupon

I am currently making an application in Ruby on Rails which requires to count all bookmarks of any given domain. I have considered Stumbles, Diggs, Delicious and Reddit for finding all bookmarks. Is there any way that this can be done?

I have looked into APIs of each of them, but did not get anything useful there. Is there any other way to directly get all bookmarks of a website no matter which marketing tool its using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the delicious api for getting social bookmarks related to delicious.
For others I m not so sure.